# Jenkins release with M2 Release Plugin

Tags: java, hudson, release, jenkins

I have Jenkins 1.434 and M2 Release Plugin v0.8 and i want to configure my project for release.
The problem is that in the project configuration I cannot see any options except "[] Execute shell script on remote host using ssh". I expect to see the ones from [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) and also see a "Perform Maven Release" button but I don't.

Do i need some other plugins? I was thinking that maybe the M2 Release Plugin has some dependencies.

Comment: Same problem here, using Jenkins 1.456 + M2 Release plugin 0.9. Cannot see it in the GUI.

Comment: Does the problem still exists for you, guys, or is it gone with an upgrade or any other solution? If so, time to close question this way or another.

Comment: It still exists. We did not upgrade

Comment: Same issue here running Jenkins 1.463 + M2 Release plugin 0.9.1

Answer (score 1):

The section *Build Environment* seems to only appear if you create a *New Job* and choose *Maven 2/3*. The section does not seem to appear for jobs created before the plugin was installed.